# How to download a Debian package of specific version and all its dependencies(including recommended) without installing?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

We can use apt-rdepends or apt-cache to download a package and all its dependencies.

But to download a deb package of **specific version** and its respective dependencies. Above commands does not support specifying version.

I just want to download them so that I can setup local deb repo on any other system without internet connection.

Note that I will not have details/access to the system(offline system) where I will be installing the package. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is asked on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory

Let copy the answer here with my updates.

```
# aptitude clean
# aptitude --download-only install <your_package_here>=<version_here>
# cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb <your_directory_here>
```

But the answer above is commented

> This only works if you do not have the package or its dependencies installed locally.

Yet another answer from there.

*The `aptitude --download-only ...` approach only works if you have a debian distro with internet connection in your hands.*

*If you don't, I think it is better to run the following script on the disconnected debian machine:*

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install <my_package_name> | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 >downloads.list
```

*move the downloads.list file into a connected linux (or non linux) machine, and run:*

```
wget --input-file myurilist
```

*this downloads all your files into the current directory.After that you can copy them on an USB key and install in your disconnected debian machine.*

*credits: http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/517*

*PS
I basically copied the blog post because it was not very readable, and in case the post will disappear.*

There are two comments to this answer above.

> apt-get approach is only working when package is not installed – A.
>
> Adding `-qq` to the apt-get line removes the need for the grep (and the need for --assume-yes)

I hope you would find the best solution based on the stackoverflow article.

Comment: Thank you so much. Getting uris best fit my requirement.